# List element rendering fault in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering

Has anyone seen this before - and can anything be done about it?  This link is to a PNG screen shot of a list display in IE - if you look closely, the line height of each element is getting a little bigger for each successive item.  The web site look is entirely controlled by CSS.

<strike>Screen Shot</strike>

It's not a huge deal, but it sure is weird.

Also, note the space between the white line and the box border - that's not there in FF or Chrome, either, only IE.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML & CSS, like it appears on the output? This certainly is not the default IE behavior.

Comment: Look on his site :p I asked the same!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in IE7.

I just tested on IE8, works as expected in IE8 mode, but exhibits the same behaviour in compatibility mode.

Update: messing about, it seems it the `overflow:hidden` style causing that.

Comment: Bingo - you're officially my hero for today, leppie!

Answer (score 2):

I see your page is XHTML and it validates... 
But like allmost any XHTML page it's served as `text/html` and not `application/xhtml+xml` (if it were IE would not recognize it, and ask if you wanted to save the file). So allthoug it's a nice idea to use XHTML, every browser gets served XHTML and told it's HTML so your nice valid XML is parsed as html tagsoup. (If you really wand compatibility, and you don't really need to parse your page as XML, then "HTML 4.01 Strict" is still the best choice)

Still I'm not sure how that could affect the list rendering (as the syntax in a list should be essentially the same), but if IE don't understand a tag it might not get the endtag. It reminds me of the effect you get if you forget the endtag on a li, and have a just a little padding on it...

Never try to get pixel perfect rendering in IE, you'll go mad and you probably won't succeed; learn to live with it. :P

Comment: Yeah I got stung by IE not accepting XHTML - took me a while to figure it out.  I am not after PP rendering, but was rather curious and thought someone else may have seen it and know of a cure.